# semantic-release does not detect old tags/releases performed before semrel integration

Tags: git, gitlab, tags, gitlab-ci, semantic-release

We were using GitLab release job to create releases whenever a tag is manually created, and we have already few tags/releases created that way, now we are moving to semantic-release to create releases for each commit to release branch, now when we try to create a release it starts with version v1.0.0-eng.1 even if we are having already those tags

```
$ git tag -l

v3.4.1-eng.1        
v3.4.2-eng.1      
v3.4.3-eng.1        
v3.5.1-eng.1        
v3.5.2-eng.1        
v3.5.3-eng.1        
v3.5.4-eng.1
```

is there a possibility to set a starting tag to semantic-release to create a release ?

Comment: Are you talking about a particular tool or product when you say "semantic-release"? I'm not sure the question makes sense otherwise.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the npm tool semantic-release

Comment: Assuming that the semantic-release code *reads the existing Git tags* before trying to allocate the "next" tag, you could simply create Git tags that it does understand. There's no constraint in Git that says that a commit can have only one tag. See the existing tags section in [the configuration docs](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/usage/configuration).